# Observable.Retry() is not working as expected with Hot Observables

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have the following observable sequence

```
int num = 0;            

var o = Observable.Create<int>(observer => Task.Run(() =>
{
    var rnd = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
    Console.WriteLine($"Starting subscription loop # {++num}");
    for (int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(200);

        if (i == 3)
        {
            observer.OnError(new ApplicationException("test exception"));
            break;
        }

        observer.OnNext(rnd.Next(0, 50));
    }
})).Publish().RefCount();
```

and the following notification handler

```
o
    .Retry()
    .Subscribe(Console.WriteLine, ex => Console.WriteLine($"Exception occurred: {ex.Message}"), () => Console.WriteLine("Completed"));
```

Here is my output

```
Starting subscription loop # 1
47
27
12
Starting subscription loop # 2
Starting subscription loop # 3
Starting subscription loop # 4
Starting subscription loop # 5
Starting subscription loop # 6
Starting subscription loop # 7
Starting subscription loop # 8
Starting subscription loop # 9
...
```

I read the following in [Lee Campbell's IntroToRx](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/11_advancederrorhandling.html) book

> If you are expecting your sequence to encounter predictable issues,
>   you might simply want to retry. One such example when you want to
>   retry is when performing I/O (such as web request or disk access). I/O
>   is notorious for intermittent failures. The Retry extension method
>   offers the ability to retry on failure a specified number of times or
>   until it succeeds.

The behavior I notice in my sample does not match the behavior Campbell has notated, neither does it match his samples. What am I missing?

It works fine if I don't `Publish().RefCount()`.

Comment: It's a waste to do `new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks)` because that's what `new Random()` does under the hood. You're better of creating a `[ThreadStatic]` static field variable.

Comment: @Enigmativity [No it does not](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:soLsS4sP7AoJ:https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/shared/System/Random.cs+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us#L126) it uses a logic involving two `Random` objects one cycled one maintained.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder when that changed. Nevertheless, it doesn't make a difference in using `new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks)` over `new Random()`. It still has the same issue of a bad seed.

Comment: Related: [How to fix the inconsistency of the Publish().RefCount() behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64961330/how-to-fix-the-inconsistency-of-the-publish-refcount-behavior) TL;DR, the problematic behavior you observe cannot be fixed reliably. The reason you `Publish` is for ensuring that multiple subscribers will get notifications from the same sequence. This can only be guaranteed with a `Publish` backed up by a statefull `Subject` (that remembers the completion status of the source). The sad repercussion is that the `Publish` is not reusable. It can be connected only once.

Answer (score 2):

When an observable errors out, it is dead and finished. No more notifications should flow out. In your case, `o` is erring out and because of `.Publish().Refcount()`, the `Retry` is trying to resubscribe to the same observable (which is dead and finished). That's what `Publish` does: instead of creating new observables, it subscribes multiple clients to the same observables.

If you remove `.Publish().Refcount()` you'll see it attempt to resubscribe to a new observable.

Comment: `Retry` should unsubscribe the dead observable which should let `RefCount` layer know there are no more subscribers, hence calling `Disconnect()` on `IConnectableObservable` returned by `Publish()`, and `Retry` should try another subscription. Is `Retry` not Disposing the subscription before it resubscribes?

Comment: That's basically an implementation detail breaking the wrong way against you. Whether it subscribes then unsubscribes or vice versa isn't something you want to be relying on.

Comment: @fahadash - The `OnError` is effectively unsubscribing - the `.Retry` is resubscribing. But as Shlomo points out, the `.Publish().RefCount()` combination is a once only observable so the `.Retry` can never succeed in this circumstance.