# How to fix the inconsistency of the Publish().RefCount() behavior?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, rx.net

Recently I stumbled upon an [interesting statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54449757/how-to-subscribe-to-iobservable-sequence-force-completion-and-retrieve-all-dat/54452463#54452463) by Enigmativity about the [`Publish`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh229126(v=vs.103)) and [`RefCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh211664(v=vs.103)) operators:

> You're using the dangerous .Publish().RefCount() operator pair which creates a sequence that can't be subscribed to after it completes.

This statement seems to oppose Lee Campbell's assessment about these operators. Quoting from his book [Intro to Rx](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/14_HotAndColdObservables.html#RefCount):

> The Publish/RefCount pair is extremely useful for taking a cold observable and sharing it as a hot observable sequence for subsequent observers.

Initially I didn't believe that Enigmativity's statement was correct, so I tried to refute it. My experiments revealed that the `Publish().RefCount()` can be
indeed inconsistent. Subscribing a second time to a published sequence can cause a new subscription to the source sequence, or not, depending on whether the source sequence was completed while connected. If it was completed, then it won't be resubscribed. If it was not completed, then it will be resubscribed. Here is a demonstration of this behavior:

```
var observable = Observable
    .Create<int>(o =>
    {
        o.OnNext(13);
        o.OnCompleted(); // Commenting this line alters the observed behavior
        return Disposable.Empty;
    })
    .Do(x => Console.WriteLine($"Producer generated: {x}"))
    .Finally(() => Console.WriteLine($"Producer finished"))
    .Publish()
    .RefCount()
    .Do(x => Console.WriteLine($"Consumer received #{x}"))
    .Finally(() => Console.WriteLine($"Consumer finished"));

observable.Subscribe().Dispose();
observable.Subscribe().Dispose();
```

In this example the `observable` is composed by three parts. First is the producing part that generates a single value and then completes. Then follows the publishing mechanism (`Publish`+`RefCount`). And finally comes the consuming part that observes the values emitted by the producer. The `observable` is subscribed twice. The expected behavior would be that each subscription will receive one value. But this is not what happens! Here is the output:

```xml
Producer generated: 13
Consumer received #13
Producer finished
Consumer finished
Consumer finished
```

([Try it on fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TO6YTu))

And here is the output if we comment the `o.OnCompleted();` line. This subtle change results to a behavior that is expected and desirable:

```xml
Producer generated: 13
Consumer received #13
Producer finished
Consumer finished
Producer generated: 13
Consumer received #13
Producer finished
Consumer finished
```

In the first case the *cold* producer (the part before the `Publish().RefCount()`) was subscribed only once. The first consumer received the emitted value, but the second consumer received nothing (except from an `OnCompleted` notification). In the second case the producer was subscribed twice. Each time it generated a value, and each consumer got one value.

My question is: how can we fix this? How can we modify either the `Publish` operator, or the `RefCount`, or both, in order to make them behave always consistently and desirably? Below are the specifications of the desirable behavior:

1. The published sequence should propagate to its subscribers all notifications coming directly from the source sequence, and nothing else.
2. The published sequence should subscribe to the source sequence when its current number of subscribers increases from zero to one.
3. The published sequence should stay connected to the source as long as it has at least one subscriber.
4. The published sequence should unsubscribe from the source when its current number of subscribers becomes zero.

I am asking for either a custom `PublishRefCount` operator that offers the functionality described above, or for a way to achieve the desirable functionality using the built-in operators.

Btw a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35692770/why-is-refcount-not-working-after-all-initial-subscribers-disconnect) exists, that asks why this happens. My question is about how to fix it.

---

**Update:** In retrospect, the above specification results to an unstable behavior that makes race-conditions unavoidable. There is no guarantee that two subscriptions to the published sequence will result to a single subscription to the source sequence. The source sequence may complete between the two subscriptions, causing the unsubscription of the first subscriber, causing the unsubscription of the `RefCount` operator, causing a new subscription to the source for the next subscriber. The behavior of the built-in `.Publish().RefCount()` prevents this from happening.

The moral lesson is that the `.Publish().RefCount()` sequence is not broken, but it's not reusable. It cannot be used reliably for multiple connect/disconnect sessions. If you want a second session, you should create a new `.Publish().RefCount()` sequence.

Comment: Why do you think that the behaviour you observed is wrong? That’s exactly how I would expect it to behave.

Comment: @Shlomo there is no hint in the [definition](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/refcount.html) of the `RefCount` that it maintains the state of the source observable (whether it's completed or not), and use this memory to sent `OnCompleted` notifications on its behalf. My expectation was that it only maintains the current number of its subscribers. In other words the `RefCount` is doing more than it's supposed to do. I would prefer it to be dumb and predictable, instead of having a mind of its own.

Comment: It’s not doing that. Publish is.

Comment: @Shlomo that would be great. In that case only the `Publish` would need fixing!

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - Your statement that the two quotes contradict each other doesn't ring true to me - both statements can be true. Otherwise I like your question and Shlomo's answer, but I really don't understand the logic behind making `Publish().RefCount()` behave the way it does. It seems very counter-intuitive. But you've help clear up my confusion. Thank you.

Comment: @Enigmativity my suggestion aims to this goal: take a cold sequence, make it hot while is has subscribers, and then make it cold again. Do you think that the `Publish().RefCount()` can be fixed in a different way than my suggestion, or that its current behavior is OK and needs not to be fixed?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - I'm sure the "correct" semantics can be worked out, but I think it's be a new operator needed to make it work. Something like `HotByRefCount()`.

Comment: @Enigmativity I am OK with the name, but why do you think that my specification results to a counter-intuitive behavior? It seems straightforward to me. I can't think of a scenario that would result to strange phenomena. Essentially what I am suggesting is to avoid maintaining any other state than the number of subscribers. When the source completes, the completion will be propagated to all subscribers. Then all of them will unsubscribe automatically, and the hot publisher will become cold instantly. And then it will be ready to be warmed-up again with the next incoming subscription.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - I wasn't saying that your suggestion was counter-intuitive. I was saying that the current `Publish().RefCount()` is.

Comment: @Enigmativity ahh, OK then. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to restart an IConnectableObservable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47739717/is-it-possible-to-restart-an-iconnectableobservable)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lee does a [good job](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/14_HotAndColdObservables.html#PublishAndConnect) explaining `IConnectableObservable`, but `Publish` isn't explained that well. It's a pretty simple animal, just hard to explain. I'll assume you understand `IConnectableObservable`:

If we to re-implement the zero-param `Publish` function simply and lazily, it would look something like this:

```
//  For illustrative purposes only: don't use this code
public class PublishObservable<T> : IConnectableObservable<T>
{
    private readonly IObservable<T> _source;
    private readonly Subject<T> _proxy = new Subject<T>();
    private IDisposable _connection;
    
    public PublishObservable(IObservable<T> source)
    {
        _source = source;
    }
    
    public IDisposable Connect()
    {
        if(_connection == null)
            _connection = _source.Subscribe(_proxy);
        var disposable = Disposable.Create(() =>
        {
            _connection.Dispose();
            _connection = null;
        });
        return _connection;
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer)
    {
        var _subscription = _proxy.Subscribe(observer);
        return _subscription;
    }
}

public static class X
{
    public static IConnectableObservable<T> Publish<T>(this IObservable<T> source)
    {
        return new PublishObservable<T>(source);
    }
}
```

`Publish` creates a single proxy `Subject` which subscribes to the source observable. The proxy can subscribe/unsubscribe to source based on the connection: Call `Connect`, and proxy subscribes to source. Call `Dispose` on the connection disposable and the proxy unsubscribes from source. The important think to take-away from this is that there is a single `Subject` that proxies any connection to the source. You're not guaranteed only one subscription to source, but you are guaranteed one proxy and one concurrent connection. You can have multiple subscriptions via connecting/disconnecting.

`RefCount` handles the calling `Connect` part of things: Here's a simple re-implementation:

```
//  For illustrative purposes only: don't use this code
public class RefCountObservable<T> : IObservable<T>
{
    private readonly IConnectableObservable<T> _source;
    private IDisposable _connection;
    private int _refCount = 0;

    public RefCountObservable(IConnectableObservable<T> source)
    {
        _source = source;
    }
    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer)
    {
        var subscription = _source.Subscribe(observer);
        var disposable = Disposable.Create(() =>
        {
            subscription.Dispose();
            DecrementCount();
        });
        if(++_refCount == 1)
            _connection = _source.Connect();
            
        return disposable;
    }

    private void DecrementCount()
    {
        if(--_refCount == 0)
            _connection.Dispose();
    }
}
public static class X
{
    public static IObservable<T> RefCount<T>(this IConnectableObservable<T> source)
    {
        return new RefCountObservable<T>(source);
    }

}
```

A bit more code, but still pretty simple: Call `Connect` on the `ConnectableObservable` if refcount goes up to 1, disconnect if it goes down to 0.

Put the two together, and you get a pair that guarantee that there will only be one *concurrent* subscription to a source observable, proxied through one persistent `Subject`. The `Subject` will only be subscribed to the source while there is >0 downstream subscriptions.

---

Given that introduction, there's a lot of misconceptions in your question, so I'll go over them one by one:

> ... Publish().RefCount() can be indeed inconsistent. Subscribing a second
> time to a published sequence can cause a new subscription to the
> source sequence, or not, depending on whether the source sequence was
> completed while connected. If it was completed, then it won't be
> resubscribed. If it was not completed, then it will be resubscribed.

`.Publish().RefCount()` will subscribe anew to source under one condition only: When it goes from zero subscribers to 1. If the count of subscribers goes from 0 to 1 to 0 to 1 *for any reason* then you will end up re-subscribing. The source observable completing will cause `RefCount` to issue an `OnCompleted`, and all of its observers unsubscribe. So subsequent subscriptions to `RefCount` will trigger an attempt to resubscribe to source. Naturally if source is observing the observable contract properly it will issue an `OnCompleted` immediately and that will be that.

> [see sample observable with OnCompleted...] The observable is subscribed twice. The
> expected behavior would be that each subscription will receive one
> value.

No. The expected behavior is that the proxy `Subject` after issuing an `OnCompleted` will re-emit an `OnCompleted` to any subsequent subscription attempt. Since your source observable completes synchronously at the end of your first subscription, the second subscription will be attempting to subscribe to a `Subject` that has already issued an `OnCompleted`. This should result in an `OnCompleted`, otherwise the Observable contract would be broken.

> [see sample observable without OnCompleted as second case...] In the
> first case the cold producer (the part before the
> Publish().RefCount()) was subscribed only once. The first consumer
> received the emitted value, but the second consumer received nothing
> (except from an OnCompleted notification). In the second case the
> producer was subscribed twice. Each time it generated a value, and
> each consumer got one value.

This is correct. Since the proxy `Subject` never completed, subsequent re-subscriptions to source will result in the cold observable re-running.

> My question is: how can we fix this? [..]
>
> 1. The published sequence should propagate to its subscribers all notifications coming directly from the source sequence, and nothing
>    else.
> 2. The published sequence should subscribe to the source sequence when its current number of subscribers increases from zero to one.
> 3. The published sequence should stay connected to the source as long as it has at least one subscriber.
> 4. The published sequence should unsubscribe from the source when its current number of subscribers become zero.

All of the above currently happens with `.Publish` and `.RefCount` currently *as long as you don't complete/error*. I don't suggest implementing an operator that changes that, breaking the Observable contract.

---

**EDIT**:

I would argue the #1 source of confusion with Rx is Hot/Cold observables. Since `Publish` can 'warm-up' cold observables, it's no surprise that it should lead to confusing edge cases.

First, a word on the observable contract. The Observable contract stated more succinctly is that an `OnNext` can never follow an `OnCompleted`/`OnError`, and there should be only one `OnCompleted` *or* `OnError` notification. This does leave the edge case of attempts to subscribe to terminated observables:
Attempts to subscribe to terminated observables result in receiving the termination message immediately. Does this break the contract? Perhaps, but it's the only contract cheat, to my knowledge, in the library. The alternative is a subscription to dead air. That doesn't help anybody.

How does this tie into hot/cold observables? Unfortunately, confusingly. A subscription to an ice-cold observable triggers a re-construction of the entire observable pipeline. This means that subscribe-to-already-terminated rule only applies to hot observables. Cold observables always start anew.

Consider this code, where `o` is a cold observable.:

```
var o = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))
    .Take(5);
var s1 = o.Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine(i.ToString()));
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(600));
var s2 = o.Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine(i.ToString()));
```

For the purposes of the contract, the observable behind `s1` and observable behind `s2` are entirely different. So even though there's a delay between them, and you'll end up seeing `OnNext` after `OnCompleted`, that's not a problem, because they are entirely different observables.

Where it get's sticky is with a warmed-up `Publish` version. If you were to add `.Publish().RefCount()` to the end of `o` in the code above...

- Without changing anything else, `s2` would terminate immediately printing nothing.
- Change the delay to 400 or so, and `s2` would print the last two numbers.
- Change `s1` to only `.Take(2)`, and `s2` would start over again printing 0 through 4.

Making this nastiness worse, is the Shroedinger's cat effect: If you set up an observer on `o` to watch what would happen the whole time, that changes the ref-count, affecting the functionality! Watching it, changes the behavior. Debugging nightmare.

This is the hazard of attempting to 'warm-up' cold observables. It just doesn't work well, especially with `Publish/RefCount`.

My advice would be:

1. Don't try to warm up cold observables.
2. If you need to share a subscription, with either cold or hot observables, stick with @Enigmativity's general rule of strictly using the selector `Publish` version
3. If you must, have a dummy subscription on a `Publish/RefCount` observable. This at least provides a consistent Refcount >= 1, reducing the quantum activity effect.

Comment: Thanks Shlomo for the answer, it is quite enlightening! I am upvoting it, but I am not accepting it as an answer because it disagrees with the base premise of the question, that there is a problem that needs to be fixed. I edited the question to clarify the "breaking the contract" issue you highlighted.

Comment: But now I am confused again. Aren't all *cold* observables break [the contract](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html) too? What about the `Observable.Return` for example? This operator will emit an `OnCompleted` notification every time it is subscribed. So it's either breaking the contract, or the contract governs a single subscription to the observable, and not it's whole lifetime. I am revoking my edit until this point is clarified!

Comment: I don't like this explanation around the idea that once an `OnCompleted` is issued that all subsequent subscriptions should immediately complete. I would feel that when going from 0 to 1 observers that it should subscribe afresh to the source observable. That's intuitively what I'd expect. Imagine if `Observable.Return(42)` only returned `42` to the first observer to connect, but all subsequent observers just get the complete.

Comment: added on another essay. I'm actually not sure it helps. Just a confusing part of the API.

Comment: @Enigmativity, That's exactly how `Observable.Return(42).Publish().RefCount()` works.

Comment: @Shlomo - Yes, I understand that's how it works, but it isn't my intuitive understanding of the operator. I would expect that if the ref count were zero that any new subscription would get a new `Observable.Return(42)`.

Comment: *"If you must, have a dummy subscription on a Publish/RefCount observable."* <== Another option is to not use `RefCount` at all, and just `Connect` manually. Or use the `AutoConnect(0)` to connect to the source only once (instantly), and remain connected until the source completes by itself.

Comment: Using the selector-based `Publish` is not panacea. You still need to know how the `Publish` works, otherwise you may be surprised with the results. For example could you guess how many "Tick" will produce the next sequence, just by looking it? `Observable.Return("Tick").Publish(x => x.Concat(x))` Will it be two ticks or one tick? And will it make any difference if you replace the `Concat` with `Merge`?

Comment: To answer your question I would guess 1 tick for both. But I'm not going to check. :)

There's no panacea for intentionally confusing code.

Comment: Your guess is 50% correct. If you find the example confusing, I assure you that it's not intentional. This was the first example that came out of my mind when I decided to test the behavior of the selector-based `Publish` before a while.

Answer (score 3):

As Shlomo [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64961330/how-to-fix-the-inconsistency-of-the-publish-refcount-behavior?noredirect=1#comment114848436_64961330), this problem is associated with the `Publish` operator. The `RefCount` works fine. So it's the `Publish` that needs fixing. The `Publish` is nothing more than calling the `Multicast` operator with a standard `Subject<T>` as argument. Here is its [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/09020f420e8069d5d78e9ee07c5477e917f0368f/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Linq/QueryLanguage.Binding.cs#L32):

```
public IConnectableObservable<TSource> Publish<TSource>(IObservable<TSource> source)
{
    return source.Multicast(new Subject<TSource>());
}
```

So the `Publish` operator inherits the behavior of the `Subject` class. This class, for very good reasons, maintains the state of its completion. So if you signal its completion by calling `subject.OnCompleted()`, any future subscribers of the subject will instantly receive an `OnCompleted` notification. This feature serves well a standalone subject and its subscribers, but becomes a problematic artifact when a `Subject` is used as an intermediate propagator between a source sequence and the subscribers of that sequence. That's because the source sequence already maintains its own state, and duplicating this state inside the subject introduces the risk of the two states becoming out of sync. Which is exactly what happens when the `Publish` is combined with the `RefCount` operator. The subject remembers that the source has completed, while the source, being a cold sequence, has lost its memory about its previous life and is willing to start a new life afresh.

So the solution is to feed the `Multicast` operator with a stateless subject. Unfortunately I can't find a way to compose it based on the built-in `Subject<T>` (inheritance is not an option because the class is sealed). Fortunately implementing it from scratch is not very difficult. The implementation below uses an [`ImmutableArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablearray-1) as storage for the subject's observers, and uses interlocked operations to ensure its thread-safety (much like the built-in `Subject<T>` [implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/main/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Subjects/Subject.cs)).

```
public class StatelessSubject<T> : ISubject<T>
{
    private IImmutableList<IObserver<T>> _observers
        = ImmutableArray<IObserver<T>>.Empty;

    public void OnNext(T value)
    {
        foreach (var observer in Volatile.Read(ref _observers))
            observer.OnNext(value);
    }
    public void OnError(Exception error)
    {
        foreach (var observer in Volatile.Read(ref _observers))
            observer.OnError(error);
    }
    public void OnCompleted()
    {
        foreach (var observer in Volatile.Read(ref _observers))
            observer.OnCompleted();
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer)
    {
        ImmutableInterlocked.Update(ref _observers, x => x.Add(observer));
        return Disposable.Create(() =>
        {
            ImmutableInterlocked.Update(ref _observers, x => x.Remove(observer));
        });
    }
}
```

Now the `Publish().RefCount()` can be fixed by replacing it with this:

```
.Multicast(new StatelessSubject<SomeType>()).RefCount()
```

This change results to the desirable behavior. The published sequence is initially cold, becomes hot when it is subscribed for the first time, and becomes cold again when its last subscriber unsubscribes. And the circle continues with no memories of the past events.

Regarding the other normal case that the source sequence completes, the completion is propagated to all subscribers, causing all of them to unsubscribe automatically, causing the published sequence to become cold. The end result is that both sequences, the source and the published, are always in sync. They are either both hot, or both cold.

Here is a `StatelessPublish` operator, to make the consumption of the class a little easier.

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns a connectable observable sequence that shares a single subscription to
/// the underlying sequence, without maintaining its state.
/// </summary>
public static IConnectableObservable<TSource> StatelessPublish<TSource>(
    this IObservable<TSource> source)
{
    return source.Multicast(new StatelessSubject<TSource>());
}
```

Usage example:

```
.StatelessPublish().RefCount()
```